# Invalid namespace root/webadministration on iis 7.0

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to access the namespace webadministration in powershell to get information about web applications running on a list of servers. The servers that I am trying to get information from are running iis 7.0 so I have found that the correct namespace is root/webadministration rather than the old root/microsoftIIsv2, I have tested both just to verify but both result in a invalid namespace exception when run. The server has the web apps stored on a separate drive F: rather than the C: that the OS is on. Is the error due to the separate drives or another reason? Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may not have IIS Management Scripts and Tools installed on server(s). You can install it from Server Manager -> Web Server Role -> Role Services -> Management Tools -> IIS Management Scripts and Tools. Make sure you have checked option "IIS Management Scripts and Tools" option as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This may be one of the problems but I am not sure if it is the only one. I do not have authority to restart the server(s) in question to test this so I will bring this up with my boss tomorrow when I meet with him and will update tomorrow. Do you know if there is a way to apply this to multiple servers at once by chance? Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: You can use powershell script to add it to all servers in one go. Following is basic ps script. PS> get-windowsfeature|where{$_.name -eq "Web-Scripting-Tools"}|add-windowsfeature

Comment: Hi Pankaj does this allow to install the feature without restarting the server?

Comment: @DenisSoto no restart needed.